# How can I use cy.intercept to stub two requests of the same name but return two different bodies?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using `cy.intercept('GET', '/details', {fixture: '/details.json'}).as('details')`to stub a request when loading a page which populates a form. However on that page the form can be edited and a new request is made once the edit is completed, what is the best way to stub the second request of the same name but change the body to the updated information?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Op decided to use `cy.server()` and `cy.route()` and this solved the problem.

Comment: I assumed this should be the case but does not work for me. Probably due to the issues described here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/9302

'Once cy.intercept() is declared for some route, you can not override its behaviour.'

Comment: If I remember correctly this used to work correctly with `cy.route()`

Comment: Using cy.route() for now. Thanks.